# r.java doesn't generate ListView and it refers to another ListView in another project

Tags: android, listview, android-xml, r.java-file

The listview wasn't declared in `r.java` I cleaned and built the app but it doesn't work. 
I even removed the `r.java` and it regenerated without the ListView.

### The problem

I used `android:id="@android:id/listv"` for declaring in XML file when I changed it to `android:id="@+id/listv"`.
It declared in `r.java` but unfortunately many errors appeared. I think Eclipse is looking at the other `ListView` in the other project which its id list anyway here is the logcat

**EDIT :**
After changing the declaration in XML

Here is the logcat

```
04-22 17:36:48.253: E/ActivityThread(674): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d0cdc8 that was originally bound here
04-22 17:36:48.253: E/ActivityThread(674): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d0cdc8 that was originally bound here
04-22 17:36:48.253: E/ActivityThread(674):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
04-22 17:36:48.253: E/ActivityThread(674):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
04-22 17:36:48.253: E/ActivityThread(674):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
04-22 17:36:48.253: E/ActivityThread(674):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
04-22 17:36:48.253: E/ActivityThread(674):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
04-22 17:36:48.253: E/ActivityThread(674):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
04-22 17:36:48.253: E/ActivityThread(674):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
04-22 17:36:48.253: E/ActivityThread(674):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
04-22 17:36:48.253: E/ActivityThread(674):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
04-22 17:36:48.253: E/ActivityThread(674):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
04-22 17:36:48.253: E/ActivityThread(674):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
04-22 17:36:48.253: E/ActivityThread(674):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
04-22 17:36:48.253: E/ActivityThread(674):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
04-22 17:36:48.253: E/ActivityThread(674):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
04-22 17:36:48.253: E/ActivityThread(674):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
04-22 17:36:48.253: E/ActivityThread(674):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
04-22 17:36:48.304: E/StrictMode(674): null
04-22 17:36:48.304: E/StrictMode(674): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d0cdc8 that was originally bound here
04-22 17:36:48.304: E/StrictMode(674):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
04-22 17:36:48.304: E/StrictMode(674):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
04-22 17:36:48.304: E/StrictMode(674):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
04-22 17:36:48.304: E/StrictMode(674):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
04-22 17:36:48.304: E/StrictMode(674):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
04-22 17:36:48.304: E/StrictMode(674):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
04-22 17:36:48.304: E/StrictMode(674):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
04-22 17:36:48.304: E/StrictMode(674):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
04-22 17:36:48.304: E/StrictMode(674):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
04-22 17:36:48.304: E/StrictMode(674):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
04-22 17:36:48.304: E/StrictMode(674):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
04-22 17:36:48.304: E/StrictMode(674):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
04-22 17:36:48.304: E/StrictMode(674):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
04-22 17:36:48.304: E/StrictMode(674):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
04-22 17:36:48.304: E/StrictMode(674):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
04-22 17:36:48.304: E/StrictMode(674):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
04-22 17:36:48.304: W/ActivityManager(288): Unbind failed: could not find connection for android.os.BinderProxy@40f77040
04-22 17:36:48.323: E/ActivityThread(674): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d0d680 that was originally bound here
04-22 17:36:48.323: E/ActivityThread(674): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d0d680 that was originally bound here
04-22 17:36:48.323: E/ActivityThread(674):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
04-22 17:36:48.323: E/ActivityThread(674):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
04-22 17:36:48.323: E/ActivityThread(674):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
04-22 17:36:48.323: E/ActivityThread(674):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
04-22 17:36:48.323: E/ActivityThread(674):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
04-22 17:36:48.323: E/ActivityThread(674):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
04-22 17:36:48.323: E/ActivityThread(674):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
04-22 17:36:48.323: E/ActivityThread(674):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId(AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
04-22 17:36:48.323: E/ActivityThread(674):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService.getDeviceId(ExchangeService.java:1249)
04-22 17:36:48.323: E/ActivityThread(674):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1856)
04-22 17:36:48.323: E/ActivityThread(674):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
04-22 17:36:48.323: E/ActivityThread(674):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
04-22 17:36:48.323: E/ActivityThread(674):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
04-22 17:36:48.323: E/ActivityThread(674):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
04-22 17:36:48.323: E/ActivityThread(674):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
04-22 17:36:48.323: E/ActivityThread(674):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
04-22 17:36:48.323: E/ActivityThread(674):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
04-22 17:36:48.354: E/StrictMode(674): null
04-22 17:36:48.354: E/StrictMode(674): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d0d680 that was originally bound here
04-22 17:36:48.354: E/StrictMode(674):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
04-22 17:36:48.354: E/StrictMode(674):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
04-22 17:36:48.354: E/StrictMode(674):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
04-22 17:36:48.354: E/StrictMode(674):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
04-22 17:36:48.354: E/StrictMode(674):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
04-22 17:36:48.354: E/StrictMode(674):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
04-22 17:36:48.354: E/StrictMode(674):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
04-22 17:36:48.354: E/StrictMode(674):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId(AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
04-22 17:36:48.354: E/StrictMode(674):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService.getDeviceId(ExchangeService.java:1249)
04-22 17:36:48.354: E/StrictMode(674):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1856)
04-22 17:36:48.354: E/StrictMode(674):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
04-22 17:36:48.354: E/StrictMode(674):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
04-22 17:36:48.354: E/StrictMode(674):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
04-22 17:36:48.354: E/StrictMode(674):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
04-22 17:36:48.354: E/StrictMode(674):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
04-22 17:36:48.354: E/StrictMode(674):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
04-22 17:36:48.354: E/StrictMode(674):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Comment: try clean the project

Comment: @DjHacktorReborn I cleaned it million of times :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exception clearly says  `Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'`

This occur When you are using ListActivity, your listView should have id `@android:id/list` so

set id `android:id="@android:id/list"` for your `ListView` in xml

Comment: it dosen't work, the listviwe it dosen't appear its empty page

Comment: @Najd is there any error in your logcat...please post if any and also post your code here

Comment: @Najd Your previous problem has solved, Don't make edit when your previous problem solved because this answer deals with current question. Solution for this is simple just  close your emulator and start again..

Comment: sorry for edititng I will remove them, I closed the emulater and started agin but the problem still, when it opens all users there is no data it cannot see the listview ,besides that the connectin is working and it appears that it fetches them in the logcat

Comment: yes there is , in doInBackground and AsyncTask . I cannot figure it out

Comment: I think it is in loadAllUsers since there was an else in the tutorial source but I removed it because I don't want it to create a new user.

Comment: can u have a look at it. may u can help

Comment: @Najd Sorry for the late reply.. it was night in India so went to sleep...I'll look at it if I am free..